# bash error syntax random number

Tags: bash, random, syntax

My assignement is to show a random number (`od -vAn -N4 -tu4 < /dev/urandom`) between two numbers in read. I don't understand why there are syntax error when I check the min value exception and with the random number generated.

My code is in part french

```
#!/bin/bash

randomMax=2147483647
randomMin=−2147483648
valide=true
echo "Entrez un nombre : "
read nombre1

echo "Entrez un autre nombre : "
read nombre2

if [[ $nombre1 -lt $randomMin || $nombre1 -ge $randomMax ]]; then
   echo "Le premier chiffre est hors de porté du random"
   valide=false

elif [[ $nombre2 -lt $randomMin || $nombre2 -ge $randomMax ]]; then
   echo "Le deuxième chiffre est hors de porté du random"
   valide=false
fi

if [[ $nombre2 -lt $nombre1 ]]; then
   nombre3=$nombre2
   nombre2=$nombre1
   nombre1=$nombre3
fi

if [[ $valide == true ]]; then
   randomNumber=$(((od -vAn -N4 -tu4 < /dev/urandom) % nombre2))
   echo "Voici le nombre : $((number1 + randomNumber))"
fi
```

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: But in the code does it work for you?.

Comment: You really should provide the error message...

Comment: apart from the problem already mentioned in the answers, your penultimate line uses `number1` - which isn't set a value anywhere - should it be `nombre1`?

Answer (score 2):

This line

```bsh
randomNumber=$(((od -vAn -N4 -tu4 < /dev/urandom) % nombre2))
```

> ```
> $ echo $(((od -vAn -N4 -tu4 < /dev/urandom) % nombre2))
> -bash: (od -vAn -N4 -tu4 < /dev/urandom) % nombre2: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/dev/urandom) % nombre2")
> ```

The outer `$((...))` is arithmetic expansion, correctly.

The inner `(...)` are intended to invoke the `od` command and therefore needs to be `$(...)` command substitution.

```bsh
randomNumber=$(( $(od -vAn -N4 -tu4 < /dev/urandom) % nombre2))
```

> ```
>  $ nombre2=100
>  $ echo $(( $(od -vAn -N4 -tu4 < /dev/urandom) % nombre2))
>  47
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Need to be clear about these different operators:

- Arithmetic evaluation, `$(( ..... ))`
- Executing a command in a subshell, `$( ..... )`

The leading `$` is part of *each* operator's opening sequence.  A few (somewhat silly) examples:

- *Subshell execution inside of arithmetic evaluation*: year modulo month,

```bash
echo $(( $(date +%Y) % $(date +%m) ))
```

- *Arithmetic evaluation inside of subshell execution*: compute 2 to the 30th, and print date corresponding to that many seconds since Epoch,

```bash
echo "Quite some $(date --date="@ $((1 << 30))" -R) time ago"
```

---

Now please consider again your code,

```bash
randomNumber=$(((od -vAn -N4 -tu4 < /dev/urandom) % nombre2))
```

where you are trying to do *subshell execution inside arithmetic evaluation*; you see now what is missing?

---

---

I think that I can guess the source of your initial confusion: inside an arithmetic evaluation, one may refer **to a variable** without its usual `$` prefix:

```bash
z=42
echo $((33 + z))
```

is same as

```bash
z=42
echo $((33 + $z))
```

; and so perhaps it seemed reasonable to omit the `$` prefix of other things too?